# Android Class Function Null Object Reference

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm writing a very simple Android drawing program, for which I wrote a class `DoodleCanvas.java`, which includes (at the very bottom) **a function to clear the canvas by filling it with white.**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DoodleCanvas  extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;   //Paint object for setting attr
    private Path mPath;     //Path object for tracing Paint over
    public Canvas canvas;   //Canvas object for calling Paint

    public DoodleCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    //Draw mPaint over mPath
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    //Create mPath from touch events
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                mPath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Class function for filling canvas with white, effectively cleaning it
    public void clearcanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

**In my `MainActivity.java`, I have set up a clear button to call `clearcanvas`.**

```
package brianslho.basiccanvas;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DoodleCanvas dcanvas; //Custom class DoodleCanvas (from "DoodleCanvas.java")
    Button btn;           //Button for clearing screen

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dcanvas = findViewById(R.id.canvas);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(clearcanvas);
    }

    //Clear screen on button click
    protected Button.OnClickListener clearcanvas = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ERROR: canvas is null
            Canvas canvas = dcanvas.canvas;
            dcanvas.clearcanvas(canvas);
        }
    };
}
```

The app crashes whenever I press the clear button. The error message is, in essence, `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int)' on a null object reference`. I've declared the canvas inside `onClick`, which I'm very sure is not "good coding", but just as an attempt to fix the null problem. I've searched StackOverflow for similar problems (and boy there are a LOT) but couldn't find anything that'd solve this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You never assign anything to the `canvas` field in `DoodleCanvas`.

Comment: @MikeM. Ahh... thanks, I never caught that. But what have I been drawing on whenever I call `onDraw`?

Comment: You don't call `onDraw()`. It's called by the framework (indirectly) whenever your `View` needs to be drawn. The necessary `Canvas` will be passed into the method. Which leads to another point: you don't want to try using that `Canvas` at any time other than within the run of `onDraw()`. That is, you can't save a `Canvas` there to a field, then try to use it at some other time. You need to implement your `onDraw()` as though you're getting a fresh, blank `Canvas` each time it's called, 'cause that's basically what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have declare variable with the same name: `public Canvas canvas;` vs `public void clearcanvas(Canvas canvas)` => program will understand that `canvas` in your function is the global instead of the parameter of function. => solution: change variable name

Comment: I've changed `public Canvas canvas` to `public Canvas mCanvas`, as well as where I call it in MainActivity. The crash still remains though.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the constructor and you have declared variable with the same name public Canvas canvas; and public void `clearcanvas`(Canvas canvas).So change the variable.

```
 dcanvas = new DoodleCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
```